# OpenMP program freezing before starting loop?

Tags: openmp

I have a program I am trying to parallelize using OpenMP - it makes a very large loop over some data. Since incrementing a shared variable (so I can report progress as it goes) is somewhat of an issue, I thought I'd break the loop up into smaller chunks, loop over those multiple times, and just report the status at the end of/outside the openmp loop.

Problem is, before the OpenMP for loop starts for the 3rd time, the program locks up. Just sits there, does nothing. I've stripped out all but the simplest code. Here it is:

```
  some other variable declarations for removed code above here 
  int dbl = 0;
  int lasttime = 0;
  int seedbase = 0;
  const char *pl = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  const double mm = 62.0 / 2147483647.0;

  for(dbl = 0; dbl < 2048 && !abort; dbl++) {
    seedbase = dbl; //(dbl * 2097152) - 2147483648;
    printf("Loop %d %d\n", dbl, abort);
#pragma omp parallel for private(seed) shared(dbl)
    for(seed = 0; seed < 20971; seed++) {  //52
      if(dbl == 2)
        printf("oo\n"); 
    }
    if(abort)
      break;
    lasttime = time();
    hps = (double)((dbl*2097152) * clk_tck) / (double)((times(&tms) - start_time));
    printf("So far: %0.2fsec (%0.2fhps) %0.2f sec left\n", (double)(times(&tms) - start_time) / (double)clk_tck, hps, (((long)1 << 32) - (dbl * 2097152)) / hps);
  }
}
```

When compiled and run, I get:

```
Loop 0 0
So far: 0.02sec (0.00hps) inf sec left
Loop 1 0
So far: 0.02sec (104857600.00hps) 40.94 sec left
Loop 2 0
^C
```

Loop 0 starts, and the openmp runs (and does nothing) then exits, and the "So far:" is printed.

Loop 1 starts, same thing.

Loop 2 starts, and everything hangs. The printf("oo"); never happens. If I change the line to be if(dbl <= 2) my screen fills with looped "oo"'s as the loop runs.

But before the seed loop ever happens the third time - it's dead. Just sits there chewing up CPU time doing nothing.

Can you not quickly loop over a openmp loop? Is that the issue? I find it odd it's ALWAYS stopping before the 3rd run, regardless of how complex the code inside the seed loop is (I removed 200 lines of code - it had no effect)

Comment: Does it work without #pragma?

Comment: You should always be able to quickly loop over an OpenMP loop. However, it's almost always going to be the wrong thing to be doing because every time OpenMP will have to recreate the team of threads.

Comment: Yes, commenting out the openmp pragma line causes the program to run quickly. It's completely baffled me. Enough so that I dropped it and recoded the app to work in OpenCL and I'm running it off a GPU now. I never found a reason why it would die there.